# Partitioning disk

Tags: partition, luks, cfdisk

I would like to have 5 partitions:

- Boot
- Swap
- 3 separate (one is 'main' system partition) LUKS encrypted partitions

I have boot partition as primary bootable and swap as primary linux swap. At this point I'm stuck because I can't have next 3 primary partitions and I'm not sure how to do it with extended partitions. I'm using cfdisk program.

Comment: You should probably specify whether you're planning to use classic MBR partitioning scheme, or the new GPT one. Starting from `cfdisk` version 2.25, it will also support GPT. The distinction of primary/extended/logical partitions is unique to MBR: for GPT, all partitions are equal.

Answer (score 0):

With the MBR disk partitioning format you are limited to four (4) primary partitions. If you require more than 4 partitions, you have to use an extended partition and logical partitions (thus not "primary").

You need to switch to GPT partitioning, which allows up to 128 partitions. All modern partitioning tools that I know of support GPT, so making the change should be relatively easy.

Comment: Is the limit of partitions the only difference between MBR and GPT if I'm installing linux?

Comment: No it is not the only difference. However, it might be the only difference you care about in this case...hard to say. https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/

Comment: What about partitions' types? I mean I can't make any partition bootable like in MBR.

Comment: I can on my fedora29 system. Bootable is the first option from the list across the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I see it only on MBR.

Answer (score 0):

For MBR you can create 3 primary partition than one extended partition. This last partition is not really a partition. It holds all logical partitions as one partition.